# What is temperature in Self Attention Terminology?

Tags: pytorch

I was reading the paper's code "Attention is All You Need" . Code linked at [here](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/76762bb08225014fb3055a9d07f0043aba972d68/transformer/Modules.py#L12).

I found this term called temperature. How is it related to the Q,K,V formula for Attention.

My understanding of Self Attention is

```
Attention = Softmax(matmul(Q,K.T),dim=-1)
Output = Attention.V
```

Looking for something to correct or augment my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the paper they define "Scaled Dot-Product Attention" as :

```
Attention(Q, K, V) = matmul(softmax(matmul(Q,K.T) / sqrt(dk)), V)
```

where dk is the dimension of queries (Q) and keys(K)

In the implementation, temperature seems to be the square root of dk, as it's called from the init part of MultiHeadAttention class :

```
self.attention = ScaledDotProductAttention(temperature=d_k ** 0.5)
```

and it's used in ScaledDotProductAttention class which implements the formula above:

```
attn = torch.matmul(q / self.temperature, k.transpose(2, 3))
```

ScaledDotProductAttention class :
https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch/blob/fec78a687210851f055f792d45300d27cc60ae41/transformer/Modules.py#L7

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the code's author decided to call it 'temperature' (maybe from 'temper/tempering'?), but it is the denominator; the square root of d(k), used to scale down the matmul of Q,K (matmul is the matrix product of two arrays) to counter <strike>exploding</strike> gradients.

upd: Actually it is vice versa, here's citation from original paper:

> We suspect that for large values of dk, the dot products grow large in magnitude, pushing the softmax function into regions where it has extremely small gradients. To counteract this effect, we scale the dot products.

Comment: I accept this with one leniently closed eye as being in the grey area between an answer and a comment. Please try however to change this more towards [answer]. And note that others might flag this as "not-an-answer" if you don't. Sadly (because you seem to have potential as a contributor) this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead still applies to you. But you will get there. Have fun.